# Vertically align absolute positioned <p> inside image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, absolute

How can I vertically align a absolutely positioned `p` element inside an image?

```
<div>
    <img class="test-img" src="test.jpg">
    <p class="tag">text with multiple lines here</p>
</div>
```

Since I don't know it's height.

**EDIT**

[image]

My image can't be a background, it's loaded in runtime. I want to place the text inside the image. What I have so far is like this image, my text is with `top: 0`. I want now to vertically align it to be at the middle of the image.

My CSS:

```
.test-img {
    height: 320px;
    width: 240px;
}

.tag {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

div {
    height: 320px;
    width: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

I don't know the height of my `p` tag because it's text is taken from database.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside" the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position text over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275606/position-text-over-image)

Comment: Since I don't know how I can accomplish that, I searched a lot on google but I haven't found anything that could help me. That's the reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't anything for CSS to do this (specifically because it has to be dynamic height) other than using `display:table;`, but at least now days [it has pretty good compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

```css
.test-img {
    height: 320px;
    width: 240px;
    display:block;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.tag {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.outer {
    height: 320px;
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <img class="test-img" src="//placehold.it/240x320">
    <div class="inner">
        <p class="tag">text with multiple lines here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try style in tag

```
<p class="tag" style="position: absolute; right:140px; top:320px;"  >
   text with multiple lines here
</p>
```

or add an id and style the id in css

```
<p class="tag" id="my_id"   >
   text with multiple lines here
</p>
```

in css

```
#my_id {
   position: absolute; right:140px; top:320px;
}
```

You can also try with `margin-top: 360px;`

Comment: I'm already doing this. But I can't define a static "top" value because I don't know how many lines my "p" will have and so it will not be always perfect aligned vertically.

Comment: And what's happened trying with relative position ?

Comment: Relative position for my "tag"? It will not be inside (or above) the image, that is what I want.

Comment: your image is fixed  size or change ?

Comment: The top absolute is the top position of the `<p>` if this is a problem try with  margin-top. (I have update the answer)